# How do i fix this Python Windows Error?

Tags: python, windows

When I invoke `help("modules")`, sometimes, but not always I stumble upon this error message:

```
WindowsError: [Error 5] : 'C:\\Users\\\USERNAME\\Application Data/*.*'
```

What's that? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Microsoft Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) website Error 5 denotes the error:

```
ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED 
5 (0x5)  Access is denied.
```

It seems that help accesses part your system that it has no access to - maybe try running one of the scripts that fails as administrator and see if it still produces an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this, but it seems to be a file access issue ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573257/windowserror-error-5-access-is-denied-when-trying-to-kill-a-subprocess-pytho)).

In context, I would think that this might be caused by read/write operations on disk. If this is something that happens sporadically (as you mention), then I wouldn't worry too much about it.

However, if you still want to look further into it, I would suggest monitoring how much other data is being read from / written to disk while you make this call.

Hope this helps