# WindowsError: Access is denied on subprocess.popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, windowserror

please read before you mark it as duplicate. :) i have tried all other similar issues in SO

I am trying to install virtualenv and i need to call a another python file.

Here is part of script: `p = subprocess.Popen([python, 'setup.py', 'develop'], executable=appPath)` and i am getting the below error

`p = subprocess.Popen([python, 'setup.py', 'develop'], executable=appPath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied`

my appPath points to the setup.py location.

I have tried the answers here: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573257/windowserror-error-5-access-is-denied-when-trying-to-kill-a-subprocess-pytho) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183934/windows-error-5-access-is-denied-when-trying-delete-a-directory-in-windows) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005437/windowserror-error-5-access-is-denied) but that didn't help. I am running my cmd.exe under Administration privileges.

I tried processExplorer to see if there is any lock the file i am accessing but no one using the file at that point. my initial guess was it's something to do with the permissions but read/write permissions didnt help either.

Comment: so what is the appPath?

Comment: You are attempting to execute a python script. It is better to use `execfile()` instead of forking a child process via `subprocess` and running a new instance of python. Try `execfile('/path/to/setup.py')`.

Comment: @alvits: exec solved the issue for now. But i would really like to know what's actually happening when i used the subprocess.Popen.

Comment: In your original code, you set `executable` to `appPath`. This is causing your issue. You can think of `executable` as similar to `argv[0]`. It should be set to python because the first member of the list in `subprocess.Popen` is python. `setup.py` is just a parameter to the executable.